# Indication when ap moves to background, when packages gets installed

Tags: android

Am writing an android application which in background will monitor the device.I want to get an indication whenever an application moves to background/foreground.Also I want to get an indication when an application installed or gets uninstalled from the android device.
how can this be acheived in android ?please help .thank you

Answer (score 2):

For the app moving to the background/foreground part of the question: AFAIK there is no way to do this for apps other than your own, which is what I think you are wanting here.

For the install/uninstall detection, you'll need to register a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your app to receive the [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) & [ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) intents. Something like:

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {            
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Your implementation                
    }
};

registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED));
registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED));
```

Comment: For the app moving to the background/foreground, it looks like your are correct . but am stuck with my applicatio :(.Thanks for your info

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark this question as answered if you feel it is complete.

Answer (score 0):

For the foreground/background part of your question have a look at the ["Activity Lifecycle"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

For notifications about installs and uninstalls you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the events `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` and `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`

Something like

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      // do something
    }

}, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED));
```

Comment: Hi Juri , am not interested in my activity moving to back/for...i want to know when other applications status change.